# Use ksh to parse a name and a date from a line and remove the line if the date is older than 50 days

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a test file with the following format, It contains the username_date when the user was locked from the database.

```
$ cat lockedusers.txt
TEST1_21062016          
TEST2_02122015  
TEST3_01032016  
TEST4_01042016
$
```

I'm writing a ksh script and faced with this difficult scenario for my level of scripting. What I would like to do is:

1. Read the line from text file,
2. If the date value of this line is older than 50 days,
3. then read the line till before the underscore character e.g. TEST1 into a variable,
4. and then remove this line.

The variable will be used for removing the user from database. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, but here's a couple hints: 1) use IFS to separate your input line into variables; 2) use `date -d '50 days ago' +%Y%m%d` and an arithmetic comparison to make your logic decision. Deleting a line from the file you're using as input might be problematic, so instead, save the lines you want to keep off to another file and then possibly replace the original file when you're done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you tried?  What are the problems you face?  What's the format for the date (probably ddmmyyyy — but it is better to use yyyymmdd, preferably with punctuation).  How might you go about calculating a difference of 50 days?   Which Unix variant are you using?  Do you have the GNU `date` command available?  Do you have Perl available?  Can you install Perl modules, such as [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3ACalc)?

Comment: Note that [twalberg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg)'s [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211373/ksh-parse-line-before-underscroe-character-into-a-variable-then-remove-this-line#comment63847531_38211373) assumes the presence of GNU `date` — and shows why it is useful.  Doing the calculation without GNU `date` is considerably harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veryone, thanks for your help - here's the solution for this problem not including how to remove users from teh database buyt it should be easy to figure out for anyone as this code will generate the user list that are older than 50 days.

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo
cat test |
while IFS="_ " read LUSER LDATE
do
        Day=`echo $LDATE | cut -c1,2`
        Mon=`echo $LDATE | cut -c3,4`
        Year=`echo $LDATE | cut -c5-8`
        Date=`echo $Mon/$Day/$Year`
        if [[ $(( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d${Date}) )) -ge 4320000 ]] ; then
        #echo "$LUSER, $LDATE"i
        echo "$LUSER" >> userRemovalList
        grep -v "$LUSER" test > temp && mv temp test
        fi
done
chmod 755 userRemovalList
```

Credit to my colleague Derek another helpers from UNIX helper portal
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/267002-ksh-read-line-parse-characters-into-variable-remove-line-if-date-older-than-50-days-2.html#post302977045

Answer (score 0):

There is a `dateconv` command that converts dates to number of seconds since the epoch; you could use that to determine whether a date is N seconds (the number of seconds in fifty days) older than the current date.  However, `dateconv` is not universally available.

You would use `dateconv` as follows:

```
dateconv -i %Y%m%d -f %s
```

and similarly to find the number of seconds since epoch of the current date; you would then use the shell builtin `expr` to determine whether that date were `50*24*3600` seconds older than the current date.

The next best bet is to use Perl.

Comment: Note that Korn shell has built-in (floating point) shell arithmetic, making the use of `expr` irrelevant — `$(( arithmetic expression ))`.