# Delete entire row if a column is older than n days

Tags: shell, ksh

I need help to delete a row if date is older than n days at specified column.My file contains following. From the below file , I need to find out the entries less than 50 days old of current date in column 4 and delete the entire row.

ABC ,   2017-02-03, 123  ,   2012-09-08

BDC  ,  2017-01-01, 456  ,   2015-09-05

Test ,  2017-01-05 ,    789 ,    2017-02-03

My desired output is follows.

ABC, 2017-02-03,  123, 2012-09-08

BDC, 2017-01-01, 456, 2015-09-05

Comment: How many lines are there in the file? If there are only a few lines it may be suitable to have a read loop and a date command to work on each line individually.   Another option might be to import the file into a spreadsheet like excel or libreoffice and do the filtering there.

Comment: Btw, which opertating system do you use? ksh sounds like AIX.

Comment: Hi Lars. AIX it is. But I will try the below script you have given on Linux. Can you tell me how to integrate below script with existing script.

Comment: I see two options: the easy one: install GNU awk. The hard one: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/38319144/4086774 and try if it works.  You might adopt it to your situation. I am not sure if you need *GNU date* for it. (Sorry, only GNU Linux available.) And that might only be usefull for small files. There are many Posts about date calculation on AIX here and on Unix.Stackexchange. Many answer point to GNU date or GNU Awk or perl.

Comment: You might want to add awk and aix tags to this question to attract experts in those fields.

Comment: Sure Lars, I've installed GNU awk. But slight changes needed. My data is seperated by comma, Can you make the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU awk available, you could use this awk script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { daysDiff = 50
        todayStr = strftime("%F")
        split( todayStr, da, "-" )
        cmpDate = mktime( sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0", 
                          da[1], da[2], da[3] - daysDiff ) )
        #cmpDateStr = strftime("%F", cmpDate)
        #print todayStr, cmpDateStr
      }

      { split( $4, da, "-" )
        dt = mktime( sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0", 
                     da[1], da[2], da[3] ) )
        if( dt < cmpDate) { 
            print
        }
      }
```

Use it like this: `awk -F, -f script.awk yourfile`

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks a lot. But GNU is not available:(

Comment: Hi Lars, My variables are seperated with comma, As updated in the question. Can you make changes accordingly to your script. Thanks

Comment: @Sunny1985 Updated the answer by adding `-F,` to the command.